# critique wanted - logo design

Tags: logo, critique, education

[image]
This is the logo symbol for a psychologist.

Client briefing: Logo should be "Friendly, open, gives you a good feeling, encouraging, creating interest and curiosity, natural elements would be great"

I chose as an natural element the dandelion as it stands for:
- Healing from emotional pain and physical injury alike
- Intelligence, especially in an emotional and spiritual sense
- The warmth and power of the rising sun
- Surviving through all challenges and difficulties
- Long lasting happiness and youthful joy
- Getting your wish fulfilled

Besides I integrated the symbol that stands for psychology (Psi) - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psi_(letter)

Thank you for your time and feedback

Comment: Hi! Nice concept! What would you like to know exactly about your logo? You can edit your question and add more details to it (have a look at the critique guidelines: http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/681/what-are-the-guidelines-for-asking-for-a-critique-of-my-work/682#682). This will help the other users to give you a good critique on precise points. Right now it's a bit too broad!

Comment: Cute. I think the outer circle is superfluous though. I think it'd work better without it.

Answer (score 1):

I think it great! I also like the fact that you incorporated the Psychology symbol in the design. I'm sure your client will appreciate that!

With regards to the outer circle, I would probably make it not so heavy, i.e. reduce the stroke to about 2 or thereabouts. I think that will give your client's patient(s) the belief that "you can break through this wall!"

The colours are fine, in my opinion... very calming.

Comment: It's interesting that you see that the lighter wall will give the patients the impression that "you can break through this wall!". The lighter wall may give the impression that the wall is impermanent or easily broken, but the wall in the image may give patients the impression that the wall is a wall and at the same time it's a doorway.

Comment: Fair comment...

Answer (score 0):

I think the outer circle is too confining and constraining and suggests confinement and controlling which goes against the brief. Also the light purple color seems a bit off-putting. The dandelion and Psi symbol are excellent and very creative combination. I also appreciate the concept of "setting free" through the single dandelion "seed" floating away. Overall, this is a strong concept and good execution. Good work!

Answer (score 0):

I really, really like this. I think the outer circle is fine, this is why people go to therapists; because they feel stuck in that circle. I think the lighter green shade in the back of the dandelion seed is a bit difficult to see and possibly reproduce so I would question if it's necessary. The shape of the seed that is freeing itself could be refined in my opinion to look a bit more curvy, graceful. I find the color palette a tad feminine but that might be fine depending on the clientele; however, something to double-check with your client.

Answer (score 0):

You will have a problem when produced at smaller sizes as will quickly lose definition. I don't see that you have used the Psi symbol and wonder what dandylions have to do with it. If you saw this 'logo' in isolation it is doubtful you would even recognize it as a logo rather than an illustration let alone have any idea what it represents. Generally it is inellegant badly thought out and executed with no or little knowledge of printing or online technica requirements.

Comment: You can clearly see the Psi (Ψ) glyph.

Comment: Although you may have a point with the reproduction issue at smaller sizes due to the light yellow areas, I think your critique is overly harsh. OP obviously DID put thought into the concept, as illustrated by his thorough explanation of his thought process while designing it. In addition, it's actually executed very nicely. Your assertion that it wouldn't be recognizable standing on its own holds no water; I have no doubt I could pull 10 logos right now from highly successful (but not extremely well-known) brands, remove the type, and you'd have no idea what type of business it represents.